# Multiple entry Schengen Visa

Tags: schengen

I am travelling to Iceland from India on 5th of April for 8 days and then again travelling to switzerland on 5th of May for 13 days. In both the cases, its tourism.Can I mention Member State(s) of destination as Iceland, Switzerland?
Can I mwntion Duration of the intended stay or transit as 15 days?